# How to decompile a Lua file?

Tags: lua, decompiler, luac

I have a lua file, which, when opened in Notepad++ shows a mixture of English (uncorrupted), understandable text, as well as a mixture of "NULS" "ETX's" and other strange symbols, before I delve into attempting to decompile this, I want to work out if it is even possible?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First bytes of the compiled Lua file tell the version where the script was compiled in.

Try LuaDec. (5.1 - 5.3)
https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec

Alternative project: Chunkspy. (It's only for 5.1 and 5.0.2.)
http://chunkspy.luaforge.net/

For 5.1 and 5.0: https://sourceforge.net/projects/unluac

Comment: Thank you, how do I find out the first byte of the Lua File?

Comment: @S.Stevens You can first try using your file in LuaDec first, if it says incorrect version, you will look at the bytes. To look at the bytes you need any program to see bytes or hex, like HexDump.

Comment: I just had a quick look, the start of the file begins with "LuaQ", is this still possible? I don't have linux or git or any way of installing luadec...

Comment: In the end I used "unluac", for anyone else who has this problem (also make sure you run cmd as admin)https://sourceforge.net/projects/unluac/

Comment: @S.Stevens Added your link as well

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this online Lua decompiler tool](https://luadec.metaworm.site) I wrote.

It supports decompilation for all versions from Lua 5.1 to Lua 5.4, as well as for LuaJIT. Additionally, it allows you to view bytecode controlflow graph and its disassembly code.

In addition, it also supports loading custom parser to decompile unofficial lua bytecode files.

Comment: Based on the URL of your link containing your user name/profile site, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must* disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: It would be nice if you either disclose it's your site (it looks like so) or confirm that it's NOT your site.

Comment: Yes, it is my website